# Internet Explorer 8 Getting Started won't go away

Tags: terminal-server, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I am managing a few client sites where the employees login to a terminal server to do their work. With the recent update to IE8 I am having the issue where every time IE8 starts up it will go through the Getting Started section every time.

How do I stop this from happening?

Answer (score 2):

In either a GPO that applies to the users of the Terminal Server computer, or in the computer's local group policy, set the setting: Prevent performance of First Run Customize settings - Enabled

(BTW: You'll only see this GPO setting available on machines that have already had IE8 installed such that they have the IE8 group policy ADM templates intsalled.)

Answer (score 0):

I use this reg hack for IE7...may work for 8.

Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main]
"RunOnceHasShown"=dword:00000001
"RunOnceComplete"=dword:00000001

EDIT- I guess I should mention what I use it for.  Well, I HATE the 'runonce' procedure on IE7.  Its an unnecessary, time consuming annoyance! So I came up with this little registry key.  Once run, it makes IE think you have performed the 'runonce' and lets you use it without that annoyance.